# How to throw am Exception in Kotlin custom getter and stop the app from running?

Tags: android, kotlin, getter, throw

I want to verify that my MediatorLiveData has an actual value set:

```
val entries = MediatorLiveData<List<Entry>>()
    get() = when {
        entries.value == null -> throw IllegalStateException("wah")
        else -> field
    }
```

I get no compiler errors, but when running the code I get an StackOverflow, because the getter is called over and over again in the `(entries.value == null)` path.

**1. How to throw an exception in a custom getter and stop the app from running**

---

**UPDATE WITH FINAL SOLUTION:**
Thanks to @zapl and @kcoppock for your answers. Both of them helped me to get to my final solution:

```
private lateinit var _entries: LiveData<List<Entry>>
val entries = MediatorLiveData<List<Entry>>()
    get() = when {
        !::_entries.isInitialized -> throw IllegalStateException("EntryListViewModel was not initialized. Please call init() first.")
        else -> field
    }

fun init() {
    _entries = getEntries(false)
    entries.addSource(_entries) { entries.value = it.orEmpty() }
}

fun refreshEntries() {
    entries.removeSource(_entries)
    _entries = getEntries(true)
    entries.addSource(_entries) { entries.value = it.orEmpty() }
}
```

I also learned from another source about `.isInitialized` for `lateinit vars` which can be used for exactly what I needed. Also the graceful fallback to an empty list was good idea.

Comment: I think simply `field.value == null` .. would do. Is there a reason you try to use the property instead of the backing field here?

Comment: Simply a `TODO()` can make a crash.

Comment: @zapl That's what I thought also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is keep the `LiveData` private and surface a separate accessor for the checked property:

```
private val _entries = MediatorLiveData<List<Entry>>()
val entries: List<Entry>
    get() = _entries.value!!
```

Better yet, unless you explicitly *want* to crash in this case, you could just return an empty list instead:

```
private val _entries = MediatorLiveData<List<Entry>>()
val entries: List<Entry>
    get() = _entries.value.orEmpty()
```

That said, the point of `LiveData` is to use an observer, so you only get an update when a value is posted.

EDIT: If your goal is to force an initial value, you could create a subclass that enforces this:

```
class NonNullMediatorLiveData<T>(initialValue: T) : MediatorLiveData<T>() {
    init { value = initialValue }

    override fun getValue(): T = super.getValue()!!

    override fun setValue(value: T) {
        // assert since the parent is defined in Java
        super.setValue(value!!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually i do want to crash. I want to force by code that the viewModel gets initialized by calling init() on it. If another dev forgets that, the app should crash, because entries.value ia still null

Comment: Added an updated suggestion -- you can subclass to enforce this at compile time instead.

Comment: Good idea, will try this tomorrow and give feedback. Thx so far!

Comment: see my update for my final outcome. Thank you for your help!